# Convert JSON data into CSV using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a data in the below format in .json file. I need to read the .json file and convert it into csv. Below are the code which i am using to convert. but it is not working.

```
import json
import csv
import pandas as pd
 
with open('my_output_file02.json') as json_file:
jsondata = json.load(json_file)
data_file = open('Name.csv', 'w', newline='')

for url in jsondata:
print(jsondata)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=json)
df.to_csv("output.csv", index=True)
```

JSON format:
{"url": "https://example.com", "title": "Test test", "meta_desc": "test test"}
{"url": "https://example.com/abc", "title": "Test test abc", "meta_desc": "test test abcd"}

Comment: Start by fixing the indentation first then you'll understand what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import pandas
jsonFile = open("my_file.json", "r") 
jsonData = jsonFile.read() #just get your json as string

csvPandas = pandas.read_json(jsonData) #it will convert your json string in a pandas object (than can convert your data to csv)

csvFile = open("my_csv.csv", "w") #you open your outpur file (for writing your csv data)
csvFile.write(csvPandas.to_csv()) #you have your data converted with the method to_csv() of the pandas object instance

#you don't forget to close the files after its doned.
jsonFile.close()
csvFile.close()
```

Hope it helps ! :)

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for the information but i am getting below error.
raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index")
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: At what line do you habe this error ? Is it with the json or when you exec to_csv() method ?